# How do I trigger an event in Knockout JS for a date input?

Tags: date, knockout.js

What I want to accomplish is to trigger an event when the user selects a date from a date input field in HTML using KnockoutJS. Regardless of the date the user chooses, I want to set the first day of the selected month.

I don't want to post the date field on a form yet. I want the event to be triggered when the user just selects the date from the input field.

Comment: Have you tried the `event` data-bind? I.e.: `data-bind="event: { change: callbackFn }"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you bind the `value` of the date input to an observable, you can [`subscribe`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to changes on that observable and change the value to the first day of the selected month.

This is more straightforward than the answer that I had previously written here.

```js
const vm = {
  theDate: ko.observable('')
};

vm.theDate.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  vm.theDate( newValue ? newValue.replace(/\d\d$/, '01') : '');
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="date" data-bind="value: theDate">
```